# QlikView11 and Cassandra Integration

Tags: cassandra, qlikview

I'm using QlikView11 Personal Edition and Cassandra NoSql data base as a data source. I'm using ODBC Connection for connecting to Cassandra from QlikView.

While configuring ODBC connection for Cassandra, I can see all the Keyspaces( Pre-defined and Newly Created) in the ODBC Catalog dropdown list and also the connection is successful.

But when I'm connecting from QlikView using the ODBC Connection I can't see the Newly created Keyspaces from where I need to import the tables into my QlikView. I can only see Predefined Keyspaces where I can Import the Tables from these pre-defined keyspaces and load the data into QlikView.

Comment: I've never connected to Cassandra via ODBC, but in Qlikview the interface where you are having trouble is a wizard that simply creates some boilerplate QV script, correct? Can you just reference the correct keyspace in the script itself?